# Dash: How to select data points either in the table which updates the plot and on the graph which updates the selection on the table?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am new on dash and plotly solutions. I am wondering if it is possible to join both approaches in the same application. Selecting the points, update the checkbox and then unselect some checkbox updating the row color. I have this code that i found here: https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-how-to-select-data-points-either-in-the-table-which-updates-the-plot-or-on-the-graph-which-updates-the-selection-on-the-table/46674, but I don't know how to do. Thanks.

```py
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'term': {0: 'GOCC:0043229', 1: 'GOCC:0098588', 2: 'GOCC:0005730', 3: 'GO:0005730', 4: 'GO:0005783', 5: 'GO:0031410', 6: 'KW-0732', 7: 'KW-0156', 8: 'KW-0010'},
     'description': {0: 'Intracellular organelle', 1: 'Bounding membrane of organelle', 2: 'Nucleolus', 3: 'nucleolus', 4: 'endoplasmic reticulum', 5: 'cytoplasmic vesicle', 6: 'Signal', 7: 'Chromatin regulator', 8: 'Activator'},
     'FG_count': {0: 370, 1: 92, 2: 126, 3: 500, 4: 63, 5: 23, 6: 9, 7: 410, 8: 31},
     'logFDR': {0: 2.6, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 5, 7: 1, 8: 6},
     'effectSize': {0: 0.053, 1: -0.049, 2: 0.046, 3: 0.025, 4: -0.040, 5: -0.027, 6: -0.024, 7: 0.025, 8: 0.047},
     'category': {0: 'TM', 1: 'TM', 2: 'TM', 3: 'GOCC', 4: 'GOCC', 5: 'GOCC', 6: 'UPK', 7: 'UPK', 8: 'UPK'}})

style_data_conditional_basic = [{"if": {"state": "selected"}, "backgroundColor": "gold", "border": "inherit !important", "text_align": "inherit !important", }] + [
    {"if": {"state": "active"}, "backgroundColor": "inherit !important", "border": "inherit !important", "text_align": "inherit !important", }]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
marker_size_min_ = 4
sizeref = 0.05

data_table_ex = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='main_datatable',
    columns=[{"name": colName, "id": colName} for colName in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    sort_action="native",
    row_selectable="multi",
    selected_columns=[],
    selected_rows=[],
    style_as_list_view=True,
    style_data={'if': {'row_index': 'odd'}, 'backgroundColor': "#F5F5F5", },
    style_data_conditional=[],
    style_cell={'minWidth': "10px", "width": "50px", "maxWidth": "80px", "fontSize": "12px", "font-family": "sans-serif", "text_align": "center", "border": "1px", },)


def create_scatter_plot_graph(df):
    fig = go.Figure()
    for category_name, group in df.groupby("category"):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=category_name, x=group["logFDR"].tolist(), y=group["effectSize"].tolist(), ids=group["term"].tolist(), legendgroup=category_name, mode="markers", marker_symbol="circle", marker_size=group["FG_count"], marker_sizemin=marker_size_min_,
                      marker_sizemode="area", marker_sizeref=sizeref, customdata=[list(ele) for ele in zip(group["term"], group["description"], group["FG_count"])], hovertemplate="<b>%{customdata[0]}</b><br>%{customdata[1]}<br>Size: %{customdata[2]}<extra></extra>", ))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis={'title': 'log(FDR)'},
                      yaxis={'title': 'effect size'})
    scatter_plot_graph = dcc.Graph(id='scatter_plot', figure=fig)
    return scatter_plot_graph


scatter_plot_graph = create_scatter_plot_graph(df)

app.layout = html.Div(id='general_div', className="container-fluid",
                      children=[
                          dbc.Row([
                              dbc.Col(
                                  html.Div(id="scatter_container", children=[scatter_plot_graph]), xs={"size": 12}, sm={"size": 12}, md={"size": 10}, lg={"size": 8}, ),
                          ], justify="center", ),
                          html.Br(),
                          dbc.Row([
                              dbc.Col(
                                  html.Div(data_table_ex), xs={"size": 12}, sm={"size": 12}, md={"size": 10}, lg={"size": 10},),
                          ], justify="center",),
                          html.Br(),
                      ])


@app.callback([
    Output(component_id="main_datatable",
           component_property="style_data_conditional"),
    Output(component_id="scatter_container", component_property="children")
],
    [
        Input(component_id="main_datatable",
              component_property="selected_rows"),
        Input(component_id="main_datatable",
              component_property="derived_virtual_data"),
        Input(component_id="main_datatable",
              component_property='derived_virtual_selected_rows')
])
def on_selectInDataTable_highlight_dataTableRows_and_pointsInScatterPlot(selected_rows, derived_virtual_data, derived_virtual_selected_rows):
    dff = df if len(derived_virtual_data) == 0 else pd.DataFrame(
        derived_virtual_data)
    dff["marker_line_width"] = 1
    dff["marker_line_color"] = "white"
    dff.loc[derived_virtual_selected_rows, "marker_line_width"] = 4
    dff.loc[derived_virtual_selected_rows, "marker_line_color"] = "black"
    fig = go.Figure()
    for category_name, group in dff.groupby("category"):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=category_name, x=group["logFDR"].tolist(), y=group["effectSize"].tolist(), ids=group["term"].tolist(), legendgroup=category_name, mode="markers", marker_symbol="circle", marker_size=group["FG_count"], marker_sizemin=marker_size_min_, marker_sizemode="area", marker_sizeref=sizeref,
                      marker_line_width=group["marker_line_width"], marker_line_color=group["marker_line_color"], customdata=[list(ele) for ele in zip(group["term"], group["description"], group["FG_count"])], hovertemplate="<b>%{customdata[0]}</b><br>%{customdata[1]}<br>Size: %{customdata[2]}<extra></extra>", ))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis={'title': 'log(FDR)'},
                      yaxis={'title': 'effect size'})
    scatter_plot_fig = dcc.Graph(id='scatter_plot', figure=fig)

    if selected_rows is not None:
        selected_term_list = dff.loc[selected_rows, "term"].tolist()
        style_data_conditional_extension = [{'if': {'filter_query': '{term}=' + "{}".format(
            term)}, 'backgroundColor': 'gold'} for term in selected_term_list]
        return style_data_conditional_extension + style_data_conditional_basic, scatter_plot_fig
    else:
        return style_data_conditional_basic, scatter_plot_fig


@app.callback([
    Output(component_id="main_datatable",
           component_property="style_data_conditional"),
    Output(component_id="main_datatable", component_property="selected_rows")
],
    [
        Input(component_id="scatter_plot", component_property="selectedData")
])
def on_selectInScatter_highlight_and_select_dataTableRows(selectedData):
    selected_term_list, selected_rows = [], selectedData
    if selectedData is not None:
        for point in selectedData["points"]:
            selected_term_list.append(point["customdata"][0])
        style_data_conditional_extension = [{'if': {'filter_query': '{term}='+"{}".format(
            term)}, 'backgroundColor': 'gold'} for term in selected_term_list]
        selected_rows = df[df["term"].isin(selected_term_list)].index.tolist()
        return style_data_conditional_extension + style_data_conditional_basic, selected_rows
    return style_data_conditional_basic, selected_rows


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine the two callbacks into one, using `dash.callback_context` to flow-control as explained in the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#determining-which-input-has-fired-with-dash.callback_context).

As possible solution:

```py
import dash

@app.callback(
    [
        Output(component_id="main_datatable", component_property="style_data_conditional"),
        Output(component_id="scatter_container", component_property="children"),
        Output(component_id="main_datatable", component_property="selected_rows")
    ],
    [
        Input(component_id="main_datatable", component_property="selected_rows"),
        Input(component_id="main_datatable", component_property="derived_virtual_data"),
        Input(component_id="main_datatable", component_property='derived_virtual_selected_rows'),
        Input(component_id="scatter_plot", component_property="selectedData")
    ],
    [
        State(component_id="scatter_container", component_property="children"),
        State(component_id="main_datatable", component_property="selected_rows")
    ]
)
def update_by_trigger(selected_rows, derived_virtual_data, derived_virtual_selected_rows, selectedData, current_scatter, current_rows):
    
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    # Check what triggered the update
    if not ctx.triggered:
        return dash.no_update
    else: 
        trigger = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    
    if trigger == "main_datatable":

        style_data_conditional_basic, scatter_plot_fig = on_selectInDataTable_highlight_dataTableRows_and_pointsInScatterPlot(selected_rows, derived_virtual_data, derived_virtual_selected_rows)
        return style_data_conditional_basic, scatter_plot_fig, current_rows

    
    elif trigger == "scatter_plot":
        style_data_conditional_basic, selected_rows =  on_selectInScatter_highlight_and_select_dataTableRows(selectedData)
        return style_data_conditional_basic, current_scatter, selected_rows

    else:
        return dash.no_update
    
# Old callbacks as function to call in the combined callback
def on_selectInDataTable_highlight_dataTableRows_and_pointsInScatterPlot(selected_rows, derived_virtual_data, derived_virtual_selected_rows):
    dff = df if len(derived_virtual_data) == 0 else pd.DataFrame(
        derived_virtual_data)
    dff["marker_line_width"] = 1
    dff["marker_line_color"] = "white"
    dff.loc[derived_virtual_selected_rows, "marker_line_width"] = 4
    dff.loc[derived_virtual_selected_rows, "marker_line_color"] = "black"
    fig = go.Figure()
    for category_name, group in dff.groupby("category"):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=category_name, x=group["logFDR"].tolist(), y=group["effectSize"].tolist(), ids=group["term"].tolist(), legendgroup=category_name, mode="markers", marker_symbol="circle", marker_size=group["FG_count"], marker_sizemin=marker_size_min_, marker_sizemode="area", marker_sizeref=sizeref,
                      marker_line_width=group["marker_line_width"], marker_line_color=group["marker_line_color"], customdata=[list(ele) for ele in zip(group["term"], group["description"], group["FG_count"])], hovertemplate="<b>%{customdata[0]}</b><br>%{customdata[1]}<br>Size: %{customdata[2]}<extra></extra>", ))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis={'title': 'log(FDR)'},
                      yaxis={'title': 'effect size'})
    scatter_plot_fig = dcc.Graph(id='scatter_plot', figure=fig)

    if selected_rows is not None:
        selected_term_list = dff.loc[selected_rows, "term"].tolist()
        style_data_conditional_extension = [{'if': {'filter_query': '{term}=' + "{}".format(
            term)}, 'backgroundColor': 'gold'} for term in selected_term_list]
        return style_data_conditional_extension + style_data_conditional_basic, scatter_plot_fig
    else:
        return style_data_conditional_basic, scatter_plot_fig


def on_selectInScatter_highlight_and_select_dataTableRows(selectedData):
    selected_term_list, selected_rows = [], selectedData
    if selectedData is not None:
        for point in selectedData["points"]:
            selected_term_list.append(point["customdata"][0])
        style_data_conditional_extension = [{'if': {'filter_query': '{term}='+"{}".format(
            term)}, 'backgroundColor': 'gold'} for term in selected_term_list]
        selected_rows = df[df["term"].isin(selected_term_list)].index.tolist()
        return style_data_conditional_extension + style_data_conditional_basic, selected_rows
    return style_data_conditional_basic, selected_rows
```

Comment: Awesone @FBruzzesi, it really helped me, but I still have a question. In this case, if i select both manually and with lasso tool, the Lasso erase the manual inputs, do you know why?

Comment: I don't know why that's the default behaviour, but I guess you can account for those already selected by checking the "State" of the first column in the DataTable and append the new selected rows. Fun fact is that the actions in the order Lasso - Manual selection work fine